# How to offer a paid update to existing users in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an iOS app, where users can unlock full functionality with an in-app purchase (IAP). I plan to release a major paid update to this app and want to offer a discount for existing users.

Since my app relies on iCloud for user authentication, I wonder how to approach this. If I implement a second IAP solely for existing users, how can the App Store reviewer validate it? As far as I know, the reviewer always uses a fresh account and will therefore only see the IAP for new users.

I see the same problem if I release the update as a separate app. I can set a value in the app group from the old app to decide if the user is eligible for the discount. But the App Store reviewer won't have my old app installed and is, therefore, unable to see and validate the discounted IAP.

Comment: You can check the receipt to see if they've previously purchased a specific IAP. Are you only offering this existing purchasers the option to upgrade or are you just showing a different IAP depending on whether the user is already "premium"?

Comment: I would like to show the new (upgrade) IAP only to users, who have already purchased the old IAP before a particular date. The new IAP should be invisible to new users. I know that I can retrieve this information from the app store receipt. I'm just wondering how an app store reviewer could validate an IAP, that is not visible to new users on the first launch (since he reviews the app as a new user). Or if there is a better alternative to implement this approach.